# How to achieve flex arrangement of divs without affecting the div's inner behavior

Tags: css, flexbox

My goal is to produce a container of cards, where each card holds simple, mostly columnar data.  The cards should wrap to fit any container size, but the cards internals should not be affected-- neither text nor inline divs should wrap.  I've worked out how to do this using `display: inline-block`, and `word-spacing : -5px` for the container and `word-spacing : 0` for its contents.  I'm wanting to achieve the same effect using flexbox and get rid of the somewhat hacky use of `word-spacing`.

I've tried numerous combinations of `flex-wrap: nowrap;` and `white-space: nowrap;` and different display types, but can't seem to get it to do what I want, which is to word-wrap the cards without wrapping the content inside each card.

Below is an A:B example using `inline-block` and `flex`.  How can I achieve the same effect using flex to make it match the behavior of the inline-block version?

```
<html><head>
<title>Nuggets</title>
<style>
body { padding: 0; margin: 10px; font-family: Arial, sans; font-size: 12pt; }
label { font-weight: 600; color: #448}
p { margin: 0 }
fieldset { border-radius: 4px; border: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #fffff8; display: inline-block }
legend { color: #446; font-size: 8pt; margin-right: 5px }

div.fields { border: 1px solid #000044; background-color: #f8f8ff; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; 
    word-spacing : -5px}
div.fields>* { word-spacing : 0 }
div.fields>fieldset { border-color: #88a; margin-top: 2px; padding: 2px 0 0 7px; min-height: 43px; vertical-align: top; }
div.fields>fieldset>div { font-size: 9pt; padding-bottom: 4px; padding-right: 7px; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid green; }

div.fields2 { border: 1px solid #000044; background-color: #f8f8ff; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; 
    display: flex; align-items: flex-start;  }
div.fields2>fieldset { border-color: #88a; margin-top: 2px; padding: 2px 0 0 7px; min-height: 43px; vertical-align: top; }
div.fields2>fieldset>div { font-size: 9pt; padding-bottom: 4px; padding-right: 7px; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid red; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="fields" id="card_0"><p>Using inline-block</p>
    <fieldset><legend>Rigid Content</legend>
        <div><label>Label</label><div>Non-word-wrapping Values</div></div>
        <div><label>Label</label><div>Value</div></div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset><legend>Rigid Content</legend>
        <div><label>Label</label><div>Non-word-wrapping Values</div></div>
        <div><label>Label</label><div>Value</div></div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset><legend>Rigid Content</legend>
        <div><label>Label</label><div>Non-word-wrapping Values</div></div>
        <div><label>Label</label><div>Value</div></div>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="fields2" id="card_1"><p>Using flex</p>
    <fieldset><legend>Rigid Content</legend>
        <div><label>Label</label><div>Non-word-wrapping Values</div></div>
        <div><label>Label</label><div>Value</div></div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset><legend>Rigid Content</legend>
        <div><label>Label</label><div>Non-word-wrapping Values</div></div>
        <div><label>Label</label><div>Value</div></div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset><legend>Rigid Content</legend>
        <div><label>Label</label><div>Non-word-wrapping Values</div></div>
        <div><label>Label</label><div>Value</div></div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</body></html>
```

[image: Both should behave the same when screen sizes vary.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to wrap flex-items:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, sans;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

label {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #448
}

p {
  margin: 0
}

fieldset {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #fffff8;
  display: inline-block
}

legend {
  color: #446;
  font-size: 8pt;
  margin-right: 5px
}

div.fields {
  border: 1px solid #000044;
  background-color: #f8f8ff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  word-spacing: -5px
}

div.fields>* {
  word-spacing: 0
}

div.fields>fieldset {
  border-color: #88a;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding: 2px 0 0 7px;
  min-height: 43px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

div.fields>fieldset>div {
  font-size: 9pt;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

div.fields2 {
  border: 1px solid #000044;
  background-color: #f8f8ff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

div.fields2>p {flex-basis:100%}

div.fields2>fieldset {
  border-color: #88a;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding: 2px 0 0 7px;
  min-height: 43px;
}

div.fields2>fieldset>div {
  font-size: 9pt;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="fields" id="card_0">
  <p>Using inline-block</p>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Rigid Content</legend>
    <div><label>Label</label>
      <div>Non-word-wrapping Values</div>
    </div>
    <div><label>Label</label>
      <div>Value</div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Rigid Content</legend>
    <div><label>Label</label>
      <div>Non-word-wrapping Values</div>
    </div>
    <div><label>Label</label>
      <div>Value</div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Rigid Content</legend>
    <div><label>Label</label>
      <div>Non-word-wrapping Values</div>
    </div>
    <div><label>Label</label>
      <div>Value</div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="fields2" id="card_1">
  <p>Using flex</p>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Rigid Content</legend>
    <div><label>Label</label>
      <div>Non-word-wrapping Values</div>
    </div>
    <div><label>Label</label>
      <div>Value</div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Rigid Content</legend>
    <div><label>Label</label>
      <div>Non-word-wrapping Values</div>
    </div>
    <div><label>Label</label>
      <div>Value</div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Rigid Content</legend>
    <div><label>Label</label>
      <div>Non-word-wrapping Values</div>
    </div>
    <div><label>Label</label>
      <div>Value</div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  That need had completely eluded me.